# How does one "run" a data declaration from a quasiquoter

Tags: haskell, template-haskell

I'm trying to write a quasiquoter for some type declarations.

I've written something along the lines of

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
import Language.Haskell.TH as TH
import Language.Haskell.TH.Quote

sample :: QuasiQuoter
sample =
   let tName    = TH.mkName "GenType"
       conName  = TH.mkName "GetType"
       nameName = TH.mkName "name"
       creator _ = return [TH.DataD [] tName [] [TH.RecC conName [(nameName, TH.NotStrict,TH.ConT ''String)]] [''Show, ''Eq]]
   in QuasiQuoter { quoteDec = creator
                  , quotePat = undefined
                  , quoteType = undefined
                  , quoteExp = undefined }
```

Now I have the issue of trying to make that type "GenType" available. I've taken a look at the yesod source code (where they do routes), but it's a little opaque for me. How does one make a type available from a quasiquoter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Import your module into another one that has the `QuasiQuotes` `LANGUAGE` pragma turned on , and then use the syntax `[sample||]` to call it. Note that it needs to be in a separate module; you can't start using `[sample||]` in the same module as it is defined in. See e.g. [section 7.17.1 in the GHC 7.10.1 manual](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.10.1/docs/html/users_guide/template-haskell.html):

> Inside a splice you can only call functions defined in imported modules, not functions defined elsewhere in the same module.

So putting it all together, here's an example of using `sample`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes #-}
import SO_30447244_Def -- this is the module containing the code 
                       -- from the original question

[sample||]

foo :: GenType
foo = GetType "foo"
```

Comment: Right, I just leave as a top level declaration. That actually makes sense - I was trying to load it from GHCi!

Comment: You can run it from GHCi to see (TH's internal representation of) the generated code by loading `SO_30447244_Def` and then running `runQ $ quoteDec sample ""`.